# User login authentication

Tags: php

I'm trying to learn user authentication while I'm building a small user login system.

I was wondering if I'm doing something right in regards to user authentication check with the my code below. Thanks for any input!

```
If(isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){

}else{

header("Location: page.php");
exit();
}
```

Or, doing something like this:

```
If(($_SESSION["UserID"] && $_SESSION["UserToken"])){

}else{

header("Location: page.php");
exit();
}
```

Token is created using bin2hex with the length the string length of the date.

Both appear to work fine. I just want to know if I'm doing this as intended or is there a better way?

Comment: `exit()` after the `header()`.

Comment: Oh wow, forgot about that! Thanks! Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both look fine. Only thing is, that I am guessing you are previously setting those SESSION variables, when user types in his credentials into the login form and clicks on submit button?

Comment: That's right. The login form sets the session variable. I really appreciate the response, real confidence builder. :)

Answer (score 0):

Might as well add unset ($_SESSION) on the else condition just to be sure that session is cleared.

Comment: I'm assuming that would be if the sessions don't match? Sorry I'm still learning. That sounds like a good way to send them back to the login form as well.

Comment: @TAG, yes. It also makes sure to a new session will be created when they are sent back to the login form. Overall, your code looks fine. :)

Comment: thanks! I didn't even consider sessions being set or not.